# How to use ttk progressbar with tkinter frame in python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am using ttk progessbar in a tkinter frame, when I load the frame containing progressbar in a new thread my GUI is frozen, but it seems to run fine from the main class, can you please tell me why is this happening, I have attached the code below.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import logging
from Tkinter import END, WORD
import threading
import time

class CardSystem(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        self.frames["StartPage"] = StartPage(container, self)
        self.frames["StartPage"].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame("StartPage")

        reader = threading.Thread(target=CardRead, args=(container, self,     self.frames))
        reader.daemon = True
        reader.start()

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        boxFrame = tk.Frame(self, bg="Antique White")
        boxFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NSEW")
        boxFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        boxFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        textbox = tk.Text(boxFrame, border="0", fg="black", bg="Antique White", wrap=WORD)
        textbox.grid(row=0, column=0)
        textbox.insert(END, "\n ttk progressbar in tkinter frames testing....")
        textbox.config(state="disabled")


class LoaderPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        # progress_one = ttk.Progressbar(self)
        # progress_one.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NEW")
        # progress_one.start()


class CardRead(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, frames):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        time.sleep(2)

        frames["LoaderPage"] = LoaderPage(parent=parent, controller=controller)
        frames["LoaderPage"].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        frames["LoaderPage"].tkraise()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = CardSystem()
    w = 900
    h = 600
    ws = app.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = app.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (ws / 2) - (w / 2)
    y = (hs / 2) - (h / 2)
    app.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: .after is not a good solution to me i need to use CardRead as thread because it needs to run through out the app, so, I have this thread as daemon.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run tkinter GUI code in more than one thread. You will need to "load the frame" in the same thread as all of the other GUI code. You can use a queue to let the worker thread request the progress bar be displayed by the GUI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, thought this might help someone, for some reason we cannot place ttk.progressbar in a frame created by some thread other than main thread, in this situation our best option to use progessbar is to create one by ourselves, i did it using the following code,

```
class LoaderPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0)

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        globals()["progress"] = ProgressBar(self, height=25, width= ws)
        globals()["progress"].grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="EW")
        for i in range(101):
            globals()["progress"].set_value(i)
            time.sleep(0.1)

class ProgressBar(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, master, **kw)
        self.width = float(self.config()["width"][-1]) + 2
        self.height = float(self.config()["height"][-1]) + 2
        self.value = 0
        self.bar = self.create_rectangle(0, 0, self.width * self.value / 100., self.height, fill="dark green")
        self.text = self.create_text(self.width / 2., self.height / 2., text=str(int(self.value)) + " %")

    def set_value(self, value):
        if 0 < value <= 100:
            self.value = value
            self.coords(self.bar, 0, 0, self.width * self.value / 100., self.height)
            value = str(float(value))
            self.itemconfig(self.text, text=str(value)[:str(value).index('.') + 3] + " %")
        else:
            raise ValueError, "0<value<=100"
```